# Subscribe on channel by criteria

Tags: ruby, mongodb, redis

Im looking for some tool that provides pub/sub model, but instead string channels allows to subscribe on some data by criteria.

I need to publish message to websocket connections each of them correspond to authenticated userwho fit numeric range mongodb query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this: http://redis.io/topics/pubsub

Redis allows pattern-based subscription (not by regexp though, but allows asterisk operator).